# SqlConnection via Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, remoting

I develop a wpf host app with plugins and want to share them SqlConnection, but when i try to pass object of SqlConnection via Remoting, i get an error:

```
remoting cannot find field 'objectid' on type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection'
```

Google and SO didn't help me and the only topic i found is with broken links :(

Can i somehow pass SqlConnection? The trouble is that i already have ado.net-based application and i don't have a possibility to rewrite them. And on the other hand, i need to provide different plugins access to same connection because they can interop via temporary tables.

Exception info:

```
(last error: Remoting cannot find field 'ObjectID' on type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.). 
StackTrace:
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Object.GetFieldInfo(String typeName, String fieldName)
   at System.Object.FieldGetter(String typeName, String fieldName, Object& val)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.Object.FieldGetter(String typeName, String fieldName, Object& val)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.set_Connection(SqlConnection value)
   at LSSample.SampleUserControl.ExecuteSqlLocal() in c:\Users\voskresenskiy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UIContainer\WpfHost\LSSample\SampleUserControl.xaml.cs:line
```

I'll be gratefull for any help

Comment: Do you really need the same _connection_ or just to connect to the same _database_?

Comment: @DStanley Yeah, i need same connection, because i need access to temp tables. Also the task is to minimize connections to database (it loads our DB too much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception call stack and using Reflector I can see that `SqlCommand.set_Connection` is trying to access `SqlConnection.ObjectID`. `SqlConnection.ObjectID` is marked as internal, only public members are available via remoting.

Doesn't `SqlConnection` use pooling to minimize the number of database connections? [SQL Server Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Could you have one process that talks to the database, then all of the other processes will request data from it, just by passing it the query string?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but the problem is that my plugins run in separate processes, that's the reason why i use remoting. Well, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) tells me, that SqlConnection inherits MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy You're correct. Could you add the full stack trace from your exception please?

Comment: sorry for late answer, i've added more info to question

Comment: Neil, can i do something with it, or i have to surrender? :)

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy I'm not that familiar with ADO.NET so I don't know if there is a way of getting data without a SqlCommand? But you'll probably hit a similar problem at some point. It's probably better to change your design, perhaps something like I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Neil, thank you much for your help. For some reasons, i can't do as you suggest. Well, this only means that i have to change my design. Thank you much again!

Answer (score 1):

We recently ran into the same issue and I think the problem is creating the `SqlCommand` locally via calling it's constructor. When then assigning the connection to it it tries to clone the connection locally as well which fails due to some internal properties which are not available through remoting.

The workaround which did the trick for us was to call `CreateCommand()` on the connection like this

```
void MethodRunningInAppDomainB(SqlConnection connectionFromAppDomainA, SqlTransaction transactionFromAppDomainA)
{
    using (var cmd = connectionFromAppDomainA.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "this is my query";
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(...);
        ...

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Bascially the connection and the transaction came from the main app which got passed to the plugin which is running in a different AppDomain (so it can be unloaded) which could execute some custom commands in the context of the main query.

My suspicion is that calling `CreateCommand()` on the connection remotes the call back and creates the command in the same app domain as the connection lives in and the created command you get back is probably a proxy to that and that's why this way works.

Not sure if my explanation of the problem is 100% correct but it sounds somewhat logical to me and in any case it resolved the problem for us.

Comment: Well, it's nice to hear, that my topic is usefull. The main trouble of your approach is that SQLConnection gives more possibilities, than only SQLCommand, i.e. passing DataReader/DataWriter will also become nightmare. But, of course, if you can deal only with commands, that solutions looks great.